# remove up to _ in perl using regex?

Tags: regex, perl

How would I go about removing all characters before a "_" in perl? So if I had a string that was "124312412_hithere" it would replace the string as just "hithere". I imagine there is a very simple way to do this using regex, but I am still new dealing with that so I need help here.

Comment: `[^_]*_` is your regex.  The first part matches everything up to the underscore, the _ matches itself.

Comment: `my @var = split(/_/, $str);
$str = $var[1];`

Comment: @BradKoch - not quite. You forgot a * or a + modifier. Your regex presently only matches one non-underscore, followed by an underscore. Now I look like a crazy person :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit more verbose than it needs to be, but would be probably more valuable for you to see what's going on:

```
my $astring = "124312412_hithere";
my $find = "^[^_]*_";
my $replace = "_";

$astring  =~ s/$find/$replace/;

print $astring;
```

Also, there's a bit of conflicting requirements in your question. If you just want `hithere` (without the leading `_`), then change it to:

```
$astring  =~ s/$find//;
```

Comment: `/g` is kinda useless without `/m` when your pattern start with `^`.

Answer (score 6):

Remove all characters up to and including "`_`":

```
s/^[^_]*_//;
```

Remove all characters before "`_`":

```
s/^[^_]*(?=_)//;
```

Remove all characters before "`_`" (assuming the presence of a "`_`"):

```
s/^[^_]*//;
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's slightly different than what was asked, but in cases like this (where you KNOW the character you are looking for exists in the string) I prefer to use `split`:

```
$str = '124312412_hithere';
$str = (split (/_/, $str, 2))[1];
```

Here I am splitting the string into parts, using the '_' as a delimiter, but to a maximum of 2 parts.  Then, I am assigning the second part back to `$str`.

There's still a regex in this solution (the /_/) but I think this is a much simpler solution to read and understand than regexes full of character classes, conditional matches, etc.

Comment: This only works if the string initially contained a `_`. Definitely not my preferred solution since you would normally need to add a redundant `if /_/` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this: -

```
$_ = "124312412_hithere";
s/^[^_]*_//;
print $_;    # hithere
```

Note that this will also remove the `_`(as I infer from your sample output). If you want to keep the `_` (as it seems doubtful what you want as per your first statement), you would probably need to use `look-ahead` as in @ikegami's answer.

Also, just to make it little more clear, any substitution and matching in regex is applied by default on `$_`. So, you don't need to bind it to `$_` explicitly. That is implied.

So, `s/^[^_]*_//;` is essentially same as - `$_ =~ s/^[^_]*_//;`, but later one is not really required.

Comment: for someone not familiar with regular expressions, would he understand that your regex is operating on $_ ?  I think it's more clear if you use:

$str = "124312412_hithere";
$str =~ s/^[^_]*_//g;

Comment: @TimA.. There you go. I added some content, to make it more clear.